# How to fetch and populate values from mysql to HTML select options dynamically in jsp and ajax for two select option box

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp

I'm facing a problem while fetching the data from MySQL database and populating it to html select option using ajax. The value it is displaying properly for first select box, but for the second select box, it is displaying the content of first text box as well as result of second text box. Please help me to find the problem in the below code. I'm not using any framework. Its simple jsp, ajax and mysql dynamicweb project.

Tried many possible solutions

Here is my code

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSetMetaData"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Generic CRUD Home</title>

<script>
    var request;
    function sendSchema() {
        var schemaOption = document.getElementById('schemaName');
        var selectedSchema = schemaOption.options[schemaOption.selectedIndex].value;
        var url = "index.jsp?schema=" + selectedSchema;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        try {
            request.onreadystatechange = getTableList;
            request.open("GET", url, true);
            request.send();
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Unable to connect to server");
        }
    }

    function getTableList() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var tablesList = request.responseText;
            document.getElementById('tableName').innerHTML = tablesList;
            console.log('tablesList :' + tablesList);
            console.log('tablesListXML :' + tablesListXML);
            var tablesListXML = request.responseXML.getElementsById('tableName');
            console.log('tablesListXML :' + tablesListXML);
        }
    }
    //  var xmlhttp;
    //  function sendTable() {
    //      var tableOption = document.getElementById('tableName');
    //      var selectedTable = tableOption.options[tableOption.selectedIndex].value;
    //      var url = "index.jsp?table=" + selectedTable;

    //      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    //          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    //          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    //      }

    //      try {
    //          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getTableContents;
    //          xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    //          xmlhttp.send();
    //      } catch (e) {
    //          alert("Unable to connect to server");
    //      }
    //  }

    //  function getTableContents() {
    //      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    //          var tableContents = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    //          document.getElementById('tableContent').innerHTML = tableContents;
    //      }
    //  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Generic CRUD Home</h1>

    <%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
        Statement stmtSchemaList = conn.createStatement();
        Statement stmtTableLit = null;
        ResultSet rsSchemaList = stmtSchemaList.executeQuery("show databases");
        ResultSet rsTableList = null;
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
    %>
    Database/Schema Name :
    <select id="schemaName" onchange="sendSchema()">
        <option value="null" selected="selected">Select
            Database/Schema</option>
        <%
            while (rsSchemaList.next()) {
                out.println(
                        "<option value=" + rsSchemaList.getString(1) + ">" + rsSchemaList.getString(1) + "</option>");
            }
            rsSchemaList.close();
            if (request.getParameter("schema") != null) {
                String selectedSchema = request.getParameter("schema");
                stmtTableLit = conn.createStatement();
                stmtTableLit.execute("use " + selectedSchema);
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("show tables");
                rsTableList = pstmt.executeQuery();

            }
        %>
    </select> Table :
    <select id="tableName" onchange="sendTable()">
        <option value="null" selected="selected">Choose the Table</option>
        <%
            if (rsTableList != null) {
                while (rsTableList.next()) {
                    out.println(
                            "<option value=" + rsTableList.getString(1) + ">" + rsTableList.getString(1) + "</option>");
                }
                rsTableList.close();
            }
        %>
    </select>

    <div id="tableContent">
        <table border="0">
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output i'm getting is

**Output what i'm getting when i run this code**

[image]

Comment: You have multiple problems in your code. You should get table names onChange of shema selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax call you need to get the `select-box`(table names) and then you need to assign that to some `<div>` . Do below changes in your code to make it work :

`Javascript`:

```
function sendSchema() {
        var schemaOption = document.getElementById('schemaName');
        var selectedSchema = schemaOption.options[schemaOption.selectedIndex].value;
        var url = "somepage.jsp?schema=" + selectedSchema;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

         request.onreadystatechange= function() 
                        {
                            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML =this.responseText;// getting response and assign to div with id->table
                        }
                    }; 
                        request.open("GET",url,true);  
                        request.send();
    }
```

Now in your `somepage.jsp` put your database code like below :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>


     <%
          Statement stmtTableLit = null;
          ResultSet rsTableList = null;
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");

     if (request.getParameter("schema") != null) {
                    String selectedSchema = request.getParameter("schema");//getting data 
                    stmtTableLit = conn.createStatement();
                    stmtTableLit.execute("use " + selectedSchema);
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("show tables");
                    rsTableList = pstmt.executeQuery();

                }
   //whatever will be  there in out.println() will be sent back as response to your index.jsp page         
       out.println('<select id="tableName" onchange="sendTable()">
            <option value="null" selected="selected">Choose the Table</option>');

                if (rsTableList != null) {
                    while (rsTableList.next()) {
                        out.println(
                                "<option value=" + rsTableList.getString(1) + ">" + rsTableList.getString(1) + "</option>");
                    }
                    rsTableList.close();
                }

        out.println('</select>');
     %>
```

In your index.jsp ,just add a `<div id="table"></div>` ,here response will come from `somepage.jsp` ,also don't forget to remove extra code from your index.jsp page .